# How to show data for previous 7 days as a column in today's row?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have data like this:

| Date | Error | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/1 | 1 | 10 |
| 7/2 | 2 | 12 |
| 7/3 | 3 | 15 |
| 7/4 | 4 | 20 |
| 7/5 | 5 | 21 |
| 7/6 | 6 | 24 |
| 7/7 | 7 | 27 |
| 7/8 | 8 | 30 |

I want to showcase the Error and Sales data fo previous 7 dates as column for each day. So it will be like:

| Date | Error | Sale | Error-1 | Sales-1 | Error-2 | Sales-2 | Error-3 | Sales-3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/1 | 1 | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |
| 7/2 | 2 | 12 | 1 | 10 |  |  |  |  | ... |
| 7/3 | 3 | 15 | 2 | 12 | 1 | 10 |  |  | ... |
| 7/4 | 4 | 20 | 3 | 15 | 2 | 12 | 1 | 10 | ... |
| 7/5 | 5 | 21 | 4 | 20 | 3 | 15 | 2 | 12 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

So Error-1 means Error for yesterday, Error-2 means Error for 2 days before, Error-3 means Error for 3 days before, etc.

My current solution is to keep self joining for 7 times:

```
t1.date = t2.date - 1day
t1.date = t2.date - 2day
t1.date = t2.date - 3day...
```

But obviously this is a really ugly method and the query time is long. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: windowing functions are supported.  If you have rows for every day, you should use lag(error,1) Over (Order By Date) for error-1, and lag(error,2) Over (Order By Date) for error-2, etc.  This is more complicated if you do NOT have one row per day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data for each day in the table (as in yoiur sample data), just use `lag()`:

```
select date, error, sale,
       lag(error, 1) over (order by date) as prev1_error,
       lag(sale, 1) over (order by date) as prev1_sale,
       lag(error, 2) over (order by date) as prev2_error,
       lag(sale, 2) over (order by date) as prev2_sale,
       lag(error, 3) over (order by date) as prev3_error,
       lag(sale, 3) over (order by date) as prev3_sale,
       . . .
from t;
```

Unfortunately, Amazon Athena does not (fully) support the `range between` window specification.  If you are missing days, then you have three choices:

1. Redefine the problem to take the last 7 days available in the table and use the above solution.
2. Add in the missing dates.
3. Use `join` solution.